# OS/X mimetype handler

Tags: python, macos, webdav, mime-types

I'd like to write a small script that implements [RFC4709](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4709.html) for OS/X.

I started off by creating an application bundle that registers the application/xml+davmount mimetype and launches a simple python script.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me to make this a .app bundle, because the application is very short-lived, and it also doesn't seem like the best idea to get people to install it into /Applications

As a complete newbie in anything related to programming OS/X, what would be the best way to implement this RFC effectively, with the ultimate endgoals allowing users to click a link with the application/xml+davmount mimetype, which then automatically mounts the share (after asking for username and password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a .app bundle, installed in Applications/Utilities (or really, anywhere).  Bundles are the right thing on OS X.  But if you really don't want to install it in Applications, how about somewhere under /Library or ~/Library, using a package rather than a drop in app.  But I know I'd prefer the .app version... easier to uninstall.